# LIKE operator in Sqlite, except Space character

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to write a SELECT command that the Space character was not important.

for example

```
My data
-------
AB DE
A EFF
A E F E
ABC DEF
```

And my answer should be this:

```
AB DE
A EFF
A E F E
```

it means "I want all the 4length word that start with 'A' and the space character is not important".

How can I write this SELECT command???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the condition in two, one for starting with `A` and one for the length.
You can use `REPLACE` to remove the spaces and just check the length of the remaining characters.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE mydata LIKE 'A%'
 AND LENGTH(REPLACE(mydata, ' ', '')) = 4;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2a4d8/1).

Comment: Tnx, But this answer is without Space, I want to Check without Space but answer "with" space.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo I'm not sure I understand, what space is missing if you look at the SQLfiddle?

Comment: Got it... WHERE **REPLACE(mydata, ' ', '') LIKE 'A___'**